# change specific hours of xts object with POSIXct index

Tags: r, date, xts, posixct

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
df = data.frame (time = c("2013-12-23 00:00:00", "2013-12-23 00:13:00", "2013-12-23 00:14:00", "2013-12-23 00:14:01",
                          "2013-12-24 00:00:00", "2013-12-24 00:12:00", "2013-12-24 00:15:00", "2013-12-24 00:16:00"),
                 value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
```

I transform this data frame to an xts object and use the POSIXct format for the index

```
df = as.xts(as.numeric(as.character(df[,"value"])), order.by = as.POSIXct(df[,"time"]))
```

What I now need is to change all the indices whose time is 00:00:00 to 22:00:00.
All other time indices must stay as they are.

The resulting object looks like this

```
>df
[,1]
2013-12-23 00:13:00    2
2013-12-23 00:14:00    3
2013-12-23 00:14:01    4
2013-12-23 22:00:00    1
2013-12-24 00:12:00    6
2013-12-24 00:15:00    7
2013-12-24 00:16:00    8
2013-12-24 22:00:00    5
```

Thanks for your help! Pat

Comment: Do you necessarily need to change the indices in the xts object? Seems easier to fix the time first and then convert to an xts object.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to change the time of the xts object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that will shift the zero-hour of an xts object by `n` seconds.

```
shiftZeroHour <- function(x, n=1) {
  stopifnot(is.xts(x))
  # find zero hour
  plt <- as.POSIXlt(index(x), tz=indexTZ(x))
  isZeroHour <- plt$hour == 0 & plt$min == 0 & plt$sec == 0
  # shift zero hour index values
  .index(x)[isZeroHour] <- .index(x)[isZeroHour] + n
  # ensure index is ordered properly
  as.xts(x)
}
```

Here is how to use it with your sample data:

```
xdf <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), .Dim = c(8L, 1L),
  index = structure(c(1387778400, 1387779180, 1387779240, 1387779241,
  1387864800, 1387865520, 1387865700, 1387865760), tzone = "",
  tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"),
  .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
  .indexTZ = "", tzone = "")
shiftZeroHour(xdf, 60*60*22)
```

Comment: Very useful Josh! Thanks. Maybe for completeness substitute x by xdf in the last line

Comment: @Pat: whoops, fixed! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `sub` to replace the '00:00:00' to '22:00:00' in the original dataset and then do the `xts` conversion

```
df$time <- as.POSIXct(sub('00:00:00', '22:00:00', df$time), 
                 format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
library(xts)
xts(df$value, order.by=df$time)
#                    [,1]
#2013-12-23 00:13:00    2
#2013-12-23 00:14:00    3
#2013-12-23 00:14:01    4
#2013-12-23 22:00:00    1
#2013-12-24 00:12:00    6
#2013-12-24 00:15:00    7
#2013-12-24 00:16:00    8
#2013-12-24 22:00:00    5
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. Is there also a way to directly substitute times in the xts object? Your answer is perfect to my question but I am seeing myself confronted with trouble as I will have to change times again in the future on the resulting xts object.

Comment: @Pat Perhaps `xts(coredata(df), order.by=as.POSIXct(sub('00:00:00', '22:00:00', index(df))))`

Comment: I had that idea too. Appreciate your help, thanks a lot.